# Get reference to object without a unique attribute

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

I'm trying to get the reference of this particular part of the page, then I can use the method `click()` on it. I was trying to use a CSS selector like this:

```
var customersMenu = $('input[translate=menu.customers]');
```

But no success until now. Can you help me anyway?

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
        <a class="ng-scope" translate="menu.home" href="#/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active">
        <a class="ng-scope" ui-sref="customer.list" translate="menu.customers" href="#/customers">Customers</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might need to *open up the menu to be able to click the menu item*:

```
var menu = $("ul.menu");  // $ is a shortcut to element(by.css("selector"))
menu.click();
```

Then, the easiest way to locate the menu item would be "by link text":

```
menu.element(by.linkText("Home")).click();
```